# IndentationError: expected an indented block opening csv file

Tags: python

I am trying to read csv file but the program does not support. it show error.

```
import csv
with open("aws2015120100.csv", "r") as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
print row
```

Answer (score 0):

Add indentation to the code:

```
import csv
with open("aws2015120100.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```